# RESTful resource Controller - why create a GET HEAD in laravel 4?

Tags: php, rest, laravel

Look at the routes below

```
+--------+-----------------------------+----------------+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                         | Name           | Action                   | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+-----------------------------+----------------+--------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD users              | users.index    | UsersController@index    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD users/create       | users.create   | UsersController@create   |                |               |
```

Why is `create` a GET method instead of a POST? What I'm trying to do is to request to `/users/create` from /register controller to sign up a new user, but that `create` method doesn't seem to be what it looks like it is...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GET users/create` route is for getting a page displaying a form to create a new user.

To actually create the new user, you'll want to `POST` directly to the `users` route.
That'll call the `store` method in your controller, where you should create the user in your DB.